# Mosquitto publish message format to android app

Tags: android, mqtt

I am working on a IoT project where i'm using mosquitto broker to get messages to my android app. But when i receive the published messages on my app, they appear to be in a weird format. how can i get the data in correct format. Do i need to change something in mosquitto configuration.

The data sent: "hello"

Received on app: [B@2df51a89

this is what i use to get the text in onMessageReceived(topic,message)
message.getPayload().toString();

Any help is appreciated.

[UPDATE] - When i publish data FROM mobile app, the data is received perfectly at the subscriber. Vice versa doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've printed out the object representation of the byte array (message payload). The correct thing to have done is to create a new String from the byte array using a known encoding (probably UTF8)

```
String payload = new String(message.getPayload(), "utf8")
```

Then print the payload String

Comment: I used similar solution. Also, this worked as well `String payload = message.toString();`